# How to call List<string> type parameter method from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

i wanna talk about ajax call of C# method (below) from jquery? Below codes (js) cannot send value to "SessionTemplate(List list)" . How can i pass value List?

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SessionTemplate(List<string> list)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["templates"] = list;
    return true;
}
```

calling method: (not working)

```
function fncsave() {

    var arrtemplate = [];
    $('#mytemplateTags li').each(function () {
        var str = $(this).html();
        var res = str.match("<span class=\"tagit-label\">(.*?)</span>");
        if (res!=null) {
            var str = res[1];
            alert(str);
            arrtemplate.push(str);
        }
    });

    console.log(arrtemplate);
    var jsondata = { arrtemplate };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/TagCloud/SessionTemplate",
        method: "Post",
        data: jsondata,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg == true) {

                alert("true");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the MVC or WebForms?  I am assuming as you are using HttpPost it's MVC?

Comment: Hi; it is webapi asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data does not have a property with the **list** name. So, WebAPI can't map it to the action parameter. Add that property.

```
var jsondata = { list: arrtemplate };
```